# Custom hook rerender does not trigger component to rerender

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, apollo, apollo-client, apollo-cache-inmemory

I have an application that uses React, Typescript, and Apollo. Apollo has built-in support for caching. This caching is used within the application in place of state management.

Within that context, I created a custom hook that checks the apollo cache and if the data is missing it fires the query using `useQuery` from `apollo/client`.

Here is the custom hook,

```
import {
  RESOURCE_QUERY,
  ResourceFragment,
  Resource
} from '@custom/services';
import { useApolloClient, useQuery } from '@apollo/client';
import { useDebugValue } from 'react';

export const useResource = ({ id }: { id: string }) => {
  const client = useApolloClient();
  const cached = client.readFragment({
    id: `Resource:${id}`,
    fragment: ResourceFragment,
    fragmentName: 'ResourceFields'
  });

  const { loading, error } = useQuery(RESOURCE_QUERY, {
    variables: {
      findOneResourceId: id
    },
    skip: !!cached || !id
  });

  // ** It is placed for debugging purposes, output will be shared at the end of the question.
  console.log('useResource', loading);

  return {
    data: cached,
    loading,
    error
  };
};
```

Here is how it is used in the component

```
import { isValidElement } from 'react';
import { useParams } from 'react-router';
import { useResource } from './use-resource';

export function ResourceGuard({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) {
  const { resourceId } = useParams<{ resourceId: string }>();
  const { data, error, loading } = useResource({
    id: resourceId
  });

   // ** It is placed for debugging purposes, output will be shared at the end of the question.
  console.log('ResourceGuard', loading);

  if (loading) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>
  }

  if (!loading && error) {
    return <div>Not found</div>
  }

  return isValidElement(children) ? children : <>{children}</>;
}
```

Here is the console output:

```
useResource true
useResource true
useResource true
useResource true
useResource false
useResource false
useResource false
ResourceGuard false
useResource false
useResource false
useResource false
useResource false
useResource false
useResource false
useResource false
```

So the problem is as you can see the hook indicates the loading state however it does not force the component to rerender.

What could be the issue here?

Comment: Do you call `useResource` in any other component?

Comment: If that `useResource` is logged out, that means the component already rerendered at this point. Hooks only execute during component render.
There might be another reason why you don't see a UI update.

Comment: @NicholasTower, yes I do use that hook in other components.

Comment: @phry, In that case, the following hook should not trigger render a component. However component rerenders every one sec.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export const useData = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setCount(count + 1);
    }, 1000);
  }, [count]);

  return {  count };
}
```

Comment: @NurhakAltin Then i believe most of those log statements are from other components calling useResource. There are exactly 2 logs related to ResourceGuard: ResourceGuard starts rendering, calls the hook, logs false inside the hook, then returns and logs false inside ResourceGuard, then finishes rendering. The `true`s you see are all from a different component which is using a different resource.